# A Question About Plural Singular

Tags: grammatical-number

In the following passage, is "These are a piece" grammatically incorrect? It feels odd to change it to "Theses are pieces" but that would seem more consistent.

"The word politics may conjure images of capital buildings, government officials, and language steeped in legal jargon. **These are a piece** of our politics, but fundamentally politics is the activity shaping the way we organize our shared life together. To shape our shared life in a way that is truly just and peaceful we must bring our full selves. Only a politics steeped in love can breathe life into law. When we engage in passionate politics, our politics will become less about legal structures and more about the people inside of them. The question we ought to ask is then: in what direction will we point our love?"

Comment: These are a piece; these are pieces - both are correct but different in meanings.

Comment: Three is a crowd, people say.